Where is the mistake in this application of Ramanujan’s Master Theorem?
Given $a<0$, $x>0$, we have:
$$e^{ae^x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ a^ne^{nx}}{n!}$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ a^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{ n^mx^m}{m!}$$
$$=e^a\sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(e^{-a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ a^n n^m}{n!}\right)\frac{x^m}{m!}$$
$$=e^a\sum_{m=0}^\infty T_m(a)\frac{x^m}{m!}$$
$$=e^a\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^m}{m!} \underbrace{(-1)^mT_m(a)}_{\varphi(m)}$$
Where $T_m(a)$ is the Touchard polynomial.
By Ramanujan's master theorem, given $s>0$, we have:
$$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{ae^x}\mathrm{d}x=\mathcal{M}_x\left[e^{ae^x}\right](s)$$
$$= \mathcal{M}_x\left[e^a\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^m}{m!}\varphi(m)\right](s) $$
$$=e^a \Gamma(s)\varphi(-s)$$
$$=e^a \Gamma(s) (-1)^{-s}T_{-s}(a) $$
We use the definition of $T_{-s}$ which is given in this wikipedia page: $$T_n(x)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{x(e^z-1)}}{z^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}z$$
Let $z=e^{i\theta}$, $\mathrm{d}z=i e^{i\theta}\mathrm{d} \theta$,
$$T_n(x)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{x(e^{e^{i\theta}}-1)}}{e^{(n+1)i\theta}} i e^{i\theta}\mathrm{d} \theta $$
$$=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{2\pi }\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{x(e^{e^{i\theta}}-1)-ni\theta} \mathrm{d} \theta $$
Therefore, we choose $(-1)^{-s}:=e^{-\pi is},T_{-s}(a):=\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{a\left(e^{e^{i\theta}}-1\right)+si\theta} \mathrm{d} \theta$
So that the imaginary part will be canceled out.
However, when I try to verify it numerically, I found it totally wrong:
My formula gives $0.05$ whereas the actual area should be $22.1$, what went wrong?
Edits: The desmos graph is here

What is your definition of $T_{-s}$ with $s>0$? What is $(-1)^{-s}$ for $s>0$, $s\neq 1,2,\ldots$?

The definition of $T_{-s}$ is defined in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials, which you can also see in my desmos graph. The $(-1)^{-s}$ is defined as $e^{-\pi is}$.

I believe you need a different extension of the polynomials to negative orders. The integral formula on the Wikipedia gives infinity for negative integer orders due to the factorial function. On the other hand, your Mellin transform clearly converges for such values of $s$.

Maybe, this article could be useful.

What is the function plotted in your desmos graph? In your last formula for $e^{a e^x}$ I believe $e^a$ should be considered part of $\varphi(m)$ and in the Mellin transform $e^a$ should be considered part of $\varphi(-s)$ to make your definitions consistent with the Wikipedia page you referenced.

Also, I believe the Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}_x\lefte^{a e^x}\right=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{a e^x}, x^{s-1} , dx=\Gamma(s), \varphi(-s),,\quad a<0\land\Re(s)>0$$ only converges for $\Re(s)>0$ in which case you'd need an analytic extension to evaluate $$\varphi(k)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(-k)} \mathcal{M}_x\lefte^{a e^x}\right,,\quad k\ge 0.$$

@StevenClark The $e^a$ is just a constant multiple because we are taking the Mellin transform with respect to $x$. The function that I plotted is $x^{s-1}e^{ae^x}$ with $(s,a)=(8.65,-0.34)$. I have given the link to the desmos graph. As you can see my formula gives $0.05$ whereas the actual area is $22.1$

It doesn't matter that $e^a$ is a constant, my point is your definition of $\varphi(m)$ is inconsistent with the definition of $\varphi(m)$ at Ramanujan's master theorem. So using $\hat{\varphi}(m)$ for your definition and $\varphi(m)$ for the Ramanujan's master theorem definition one has $\varphi(m)=e^a, \hat{\varphi}(m)$.

The Wikipedia article at your link gives the contour integral representation $$T_n(x)=\frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \oint \frac{e^{\left(e^t-1\right) x}}{t^{n+1}} , dt$$ but I don't see the integral representation you're using in your question. Also, isn't $T_n(x)$ only defined for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\land n\ge0$, so can you really evaluate it at a negative rational value of $n$?

The formula given by Wikipedia seems to work for $n\in\mathcal{R}$, if I replace $n!$ with $\Gamma(n+1)$. I’ll update the details.

@StevenClark I can drag out the $e^a$ from the Mellin transform, i.e. $\mathcal{M}_x[e^af(x)]=e^a\mathcal{M}_x[f(x)]$, so there is no difference.

Ramanujan's master theorem relates the power-series expansion
$$g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\varphi(k)}{k!}(-x)^k\tag{1}$$
to the Mellin transform
$$\mathcal{M}_x[g(x)](s)=\int_0^{\infty} g(x)\, x^{s-1} \, dx=\Gamma(s)\, \varphi(-s)\tag{2}.$$

With respect to the question, this answer focuses on the case $a=-1$ where
$$g(x)=e^{-e^x}\tag{3}$$
and
$$\varphi(k)=e^{-1}\, (-1)^k\, B_k(-1)\tag{4}$$
where $B_n(x)$ is the Bell polynomial (also known as the Touchard polynomial).

There are many analytic extensions of $\varphi(k)$ defined in formula (4) above, but the analytic extension
$$\varphi(s)=e^{-1}\, (-1)^s\, T_s(-1),\quad T_s(-1)=\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{2 \pi} \int\limits_0^{2 \pi} e^{-\left(e^{e^{i \theta}}-1\right)-i \theta s} \, d\theta\tag{5}$$
that you're using isn't consistent with the Mellin transform defined in formula (2) above.

On the other hand, the analytic extension
$$\varphi(s)=\lim\limits_{N, f\to\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1)}{2 n-1} \left(\frac{3 F(0)}{8}\\+\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right) \left(F\left(-\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) \left(1+\frac{i \pi k}{2 n-1}\right)^s+F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) \left(1-\frac{i \pi k}{2 n-1}\right)^s\right)\\-\frac{1}{8} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k \left(F\left(-\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) \left(1+\frac{i \pi k}{4 n-2}\right)^s+F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) \left(1-\frac{i \pi k}{4 n-2}\right)^s\right)\right)\right)\tag{6}$$
of $\varphi(k)$ defined in formula (4) above is consistent with the Mellin transform defined in formula (2) above where in formula (6) above $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, the parameter $f$ in the upper evaluation limits of the two inner sums over $k$ is assumed to be a positive integer, and
$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_t\left[e^{t-e^t}\right](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{t-e^t}\, e^{-2 i \pi \omega t} \, dt=\Gamma(1-2 i \pi \omega)\tag{7}$$
is the Fourier transform of $f(t)=e^{t-e^t}$.

Figures (1), (2), and (3) below illustrate $\Gamma(s)\, \varphi(-s)$ and $\varphi(-s)$ derived from formulas (2), (5), and (6) above in blue, green, and orange respectively where the Mellin transform of $g(x)=e^{-e^x}$ in formula (2) above and $T_s(-1)$ in formula (5) for $\varphi(s)$ above are both evaluated using numeric integration and $\varphi(s)$ in formula (6) above is evaluated using the upper evaluation limits $N=20$ and $f=8$. Note the orange curve associated with formula (6) above essentially hides the blue curve associated with formula (2) (except when $s$ is very close to zero) whereas the green curve illustrates formula (5) evaluates noticeably different. The red discrete evaluation points in Figures (2) and (3) below illustrate $\varphi(-s)$ at $s=0$ and negative integer values of $s$ using the definition of $\varphi(k)$ in formula (4) above.

Figure (1): Illustration of $\Gamma(s)\, \varphi(-s)$ derived from formulas (2), (5), and (6) above in blue, green, and orange respectively


Figure (2): Illustration of $\varphi(-s)$ derived from formulas (2), (5), and (6) above in blue, green, and orange respectively


Figure (3): Illustration of $\varphi(-s)$ derived from formulas (2), (5), and (6) above in blue, green, and orange respectively

The following table illustrates $\varphi(k)$ evaluated using formulas (4), (5), and (6) above where $T_s(-1)$ in formula (5) for $\varphi(s)$ above is evaluated using numeric integration and $\varphi(s)$ in formula (6) above is evaluated using the upper evaluation limits $N=20$ and $f=8$. Note for non-negative integer values of $k$ formulas (5) and (6) above both evaluate extremely close to the reference function defined in formula (4).
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{} & \text{} & \phi(k) & \text{} \\
 k & \text{Formula (4)} & \text{Formula (6)} & \text{Formula (5)} \\
 0 & 0.367879 & 0.367879 & 0.367879 \\
 1 & 0.367879 & 0.367879 & 0.367879 \\
 2 & 0. & -8.89906 \times 10^{-16} & -1.65048 \times 10^{-18} \\
 3 & -0.367879 & -0.367879 & -0.367879 \\
 4 & 0.367879 & 0.367879 & 0.367879 \\
 5 & 0.735759 & 0.735759 & 0.735759 \\
\end{array}$$

The following table illustrates $\varphi(-s)$ derived from formulas (2), (5), and (6) above where formula (2) above and $T_s(-1)$ in formula (5) for $\varphi(s)$ above are both evaluated using numeric integration and $\varphi(s)$ in formula (6) above is evaluated using the upper evaluation limits $N=20$ and $f=8$. Note in this case formula (6) evaluates essentially identical to formula (2) (divided by $\Gamma(s)$) whereas the evaluation of formula (5) is noticeably different. This difference in the evaluation of formula (5) is more noticeable in Figure (1) above where its multiplied by $\Gamma(s)$.
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{} & \text{} & \phi(-s) & \text{} \\
 \text{Hold}[s] & \text{Formula (2)} & \text{Formula (6)} & \text{Formula (5)} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0.297102 & 0.297102 & 0.287513 \\
 \frac{3}{2} & 0.150888 & 0.150888 & 0.127455 \\
 \frac{5}{2} & 0.0603332 & 0.0603332 & 0.0407642 \\
 \frac{7}{2} & 0.0202055 & 0.0202055 & 0.0101187 \\
 \frac{9}{2} & 0.00587504 & 0.00587504 & 0.0020426 \\
 \frac{11}{2} & 0.00151851 & 0.00151851 & 0.000346444 \\
\end{array}$$

The formula (5) and (6) evaluations illustrated in the two tables above actually have extremely small imaginary parts where the order of magnitude ranges from $10^{-14}$ to $10^{-19}$ which is not included in the two tables above. Likewise, Figures (1) to (3) above only illustrate the real parts of formulas (5) and (6) above while ignoring the extremely small imaginary parts in their evaluations.

Formula (6) above for $\varphi(s)$ is derived from formula (5) in my question on a conjectured Fourier inversion theorem which I initially posted to Math StackExchange here and later cross-posted to Math Overflow here.

Just curious to ask, does formula $(5)$ give a real result, or is it just a coincident that its imaginary part is so small?

@Mr.W I believe $\varphi(s)$ defined in formula (5) is a valid analytic extension of $\varphi(k)$ defined in formula (4), but its just not consistent with the one associated with the Fourier transform. I attribute the extremely small imaginary part in the evaluation of formula (5) to precision errors in evaluation of formula (5) which includes a numerical evaluation of the integral associated with $T_s(-1)$.
